# Java JAXB unmarshal object oriented

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Trying to come up with a more object oriented way to unmarshal from xml to my models. Currently using some version of JAXB to unmarshal a string xml, and I am calling some static method passing the class and string and returning an object.

```
 public static Object unmarshallSomething(Class someClass, String xml) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(someClass);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaler = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
        return unmarshaler.unmarshal(reader);
    }
```

Thinking of creating a class which all my models could extend.

```
public class GenericModel {

    public <T> T  unmarshal(String xml) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(this.getClass());
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
        return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    }
}
```

UserModel

```
public class UserModel extends GenericModel
{
//some xml annotations

}
```

Now I could create a UserMode like this;

```
new UserModel().build(xml);
```

Is this the right object oriented approach to this type of problem?

Comment: I would keep the model classes as simple as I can. Just put the generic method as a static method in a util class and use it when ever it is necessary. This will create a more loosely coupled app. The entities should be just that-entities, do not add unnessessary logic to them :)

Comment: That what I've done previously. Is this really adding any unnecessary logic to entities?

Comment: I agree with @user3719857. Inheritance to use a method that should be static is not a good choice